# Java string input not working correctly

Tags: java, string, input

I have made this program and I have gotten stuck. When I run it and I have inputs without using spaces it works fine, for example just `Bob` input in customer input. However, when I enter `Bob White`, it merges the next two string input directions (as Shown in pic attached) . What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Blah{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String customerName;
        System.out.println("Enter customer name: ");        
        customerName = in.next(); 

        String customerAddress; 
        System.out.println("Enter customer address: ");         
        customerAddress = in.next();

        String customerPhoneNumber;
        System.out.println("Enter customer phone number: ");            
        customerPhoneNumber = in.next();

        in.close();
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Use `Scanner#nextLine()` (instead of `Scanner#next()`).

Comment: Thank you Elliott, I'm new to it and could not for the life of me work out what I did wrong, cheers mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the Scanner#next method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine

Try using nextLine() method instead with trem() method

```
customerName = in.nextLine().trim();
```

Comment: In case of int use: Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); or Double.toString(double) in case of double.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the entire line using [nextLine() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) then trim it from leading and trailing whitespace using [trim() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

```
customerName = in.nextLine().trim();
customerAddress = in.next().trim();
customerPhoneNumber = in.next().trim();
```